# Is MVC the best way to code asp.net applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

update:  I know there is no one best way to do everything.  Sorry for not saying that right off.  In the context of the data-access tutorials, if you had to do the project he did in that tutorial, would you do what he did or would use use MVC, if you had to choose one of them?

**Update:** Is MVC the more appropriate way to program asp.net applications, instead of the tutorials found here:

http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/

**Original:**

I ask, because I initially learned about MVC with Java applications, then things like RoR, and Django.  These other projects and companies spoke as if MVC had been around for a very long time, and from what I found out it had.  Then Microsoft started putting MVC into the .net framework.

I ask because I don't know how to design things very well and thought I was doing well to emulate what's on the asp.net site with Scott Mitchell's tutorial.  I thought that creating abstract layers in a BLL was the way to go until I found out about MVC and now asp.net's MVC.

I honestly don't know what the "right" way is to do things.  I just create what I need, but I can't help feel like I am missing something.

Is MVC the correct way to start doing things in large projects, specifically I mean MVC and ASP.NET, but could just as well mean PHP and one of their MVC frameworks.

I'd like to settle on a standard way of doing things...for now anyway.

And, out of curiosity, why did Microsoft only now start doing MVC?

**UPDATE:** Is MVC better than the current tutorial set on asp.net?

I'm referring to the Scott Mitchell tutorials where he creates the BLL for abstraction.  Or is that a linq question as well.  I should have said that I understand the need for keeping logic and presentation separate but unsure the best way to do it.  I was using the asp.net tutorials.  It worked fine.  Then I found out the rest of the world, as I saw it anyway, was using MVC.  Then Microsoft started developing MVC, so to me the other method seems obsolete and the wrong way to do things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it's not the only best way to do things.

MVC is just a design pattern. The goal of all design patterns is simplicity. So as long as it makes your design simpler, go with it. If it makes things more complex for your specific application, try a different approach.

Unfortunately, some people think if they see a pattern, they should use it. It's just not true. Design patterns don't inherently make your application better. They are not an end. They are a means to an end (which is simplicity). So you should use them only if they are worth it.

In my opinion, over-architecting things without a good reason is worse than writing code without any specific design.

**EDIT:** Regarding ASP.NET MVC: I have a negative personal bias toward ASP.NET Web forms. Before MVC, I did most of the dynamic aspects of advanced projects by writing custom handlers to have fine grained control over the HTML. Web Forms make Web development very easy but they have particularly a couple things that are good but sometimes are problematic. The first of which is `ViewState` and the second is complex `WebControl` architecture. Don't get me wrong. Those are signs of brilliance of ASP.NET. I haven't seen a single platform for Web development as easy as ASP.NET Web Forms and this is only because of great `WebControl` support which requires `ViewState`. However, in some projects, you want to have precise control on rendered HTML (specially when you have some client-side logic). You also want to make server side code maintainable in large projects. In those areas, ASP.NET MVC really shines. But I think ASP.NET Web Forms will remain a great technology where it's more applicable. After all, as I said regarding design patterns in general, you should carefully evaluate your design to see which one better fits your needs.

Specifically, about data access, MVC usually requires more code than Web Forms counterparts. For presenting tabular data (i.e where GridView is applicable), I think ASP.NET Web Forms is the easier way to accomplish things. However, most data driven Web apps are not just manipulating a table directly in a database. They have complex layout. StackOverflow is a great example of this. It is certainly data driven, but ASP.NET MVC better suits it.

Answer (score 8):

There is no "right" way to do things without knowing what "things" are. MVC is a [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_(computer_science)) that solves a specific common problem - separation of presentational and domain logic. Every design pattern is a commonly accepted "good" solution to a specific problem.

Those solutions, combined with knowledge and experience are building blocks for a good design. The "right" way to do things is to study your problem domain, research on possible solutions and apply the set of solutions that work best to solve it. Making mistakes is a part of the process as well, so don't be afraid to experiment and then [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) with rigor until you reach the solution that serves you best.

Answer (score 3):

MVC is the worst way to develop applications, except for all other ways that have been tried.  :-)

Joking aside, MVC is one application design that encourages us not to write spaghetti code.  It's a guideline that reminds us to keep business code separate from presentation code.  This is very helpful as the application gets more complex.

There are other variations that achieve that same benefit, but are not strictly the same as MVC.  [Presentation-abstraction-control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation-abstraction-control) (PAC) is one example.

As for why Microsoft is so late in adopting MVC, I'm not surprised that they are.  They are pretty well-known (at least in recent years) for being conservative instead of innovative.  They prefer to let other smaller companies take the risks in an unproven market, then they learn from the mistakes, churn out an overengineered competitor solution, and dominate through marketing.

Example:  Microsoft Internet Explorer was considered to be a latecomer to the browser market.  Netscape had become very popular, leading the way in providing a platform for people to view HTML.  Once the amount of HTML content on the Internet was at a useful level, Microsoft belched up their onomatopoeic "IE" product and quickly captured an overwhelming market share.

Comment: I think you have it backwards; the webforms design was different and unproven. MVC was first defined at the Xerox PARC for the Alto's GUI, and can be found nearly everywhere.

Comment: WebForms is a conceptual clone of, and successor to, Visual Basic 1 thru 6/VBA. Which Microsoft originally acquired from Alan Cooper.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is just one way of doing things. I like it because it helps to promote extensibility and is structured to allow testing and code reuse. There is no silver bullet, one true way to do everything but I use it quite often.

In regard to Microsoft, I would say that they adopted the pattern as an alternative to WebForms development for the reasons I mentioned above. I would recommend looking at [Rob Conery's MVC Storefront](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/mvc-storefront-part-1/) and kind of play around with the examples to see how it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "best" way to code things.  It depends on the application in question; sometimes MVC is the right choice, and sometimes it's not.  A good developer is able to weigh his/her options and choose the one that's best suited for a task at hand, instead of just going with the *method du jour*

Answer (score 1):

If MVC solves the **Primary Technical Imperative** of managing complexity in your application then it may be a good solution, but it is by no means the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is one of any number of design patterns. Whether it's the best technologically, or the simplest, or for what types of projects it's appropriate, are are all arguable (see other SO threads). In any case, few would argue against the prevailing consensus that for most cases, it's "Good Enough".

But it has the undeniable benefit that a lot of people use it, on a lot of different platforms.

So if you want to use a methodology that is likely to be around a while; or you don't want to depend on one vendor for support and extension and refinement; or you work in a group that would like to grow by hiring people from various backgrounds who will grok a shared methodology quickly; or you would like to maximize your opportunities to move on if you need to, then MVC is one of the very best ways to support those goals.

Comment: Is that a benefit?  The same could be said of `goto`.

Comment: Except I think that "goto" is *not* widely used - it's been pretty well extirpated. Even designed out of some languages (at the cost of occasional pain, probably ...)

Answer (score 1):

MVC being "Better" or "Worse" pattern is relative to the project.

Comment: how about the project I referenced?  which would you choose?  thank you.