# MVC posting back

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new at MVC in Asp.Net and while i am reading about the MVC and it's benefits and why we use this architechure in Asp.Net i didn't know (or misunderstanding) why we use this concept in Asp.Net? but i read an article said that :

WebForms was a bad model that only led people to develop poorly performing web applications.They were largely attributed to the Post-back paradigm that was utilized by most Web Form controls. In any case, MVC tends to be a better pattern because when you Post Back, you are generally going to be more aware of it (because you will probably have to implement some code in the controller). It is not a transparent operation like it tended to be in Web Forms.

So what is the different between posting back in web form and posting back in Asp.net? as in both cases an event is triggered and the form is posted back to server even for the controller and even the form itself so can any one tell me what is the difference ? and why MVC in Asp.Net? what are radicals benefits of MVC in Asp.Net?

Thanks in advance but this will help me more in my application as i am doing some searches b4 building the application to utlilize effectively this new technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question itself is **NOT** right.

The MVC Framework **doesn't** support classic postbacks and viewstate and doesn't consider any URL as the endpoint to a physical server file to parse and compile to a class.

Instead, when you submit a mvc form, it maps to an action inside a controller, and the controller will decide what kind of view to render at the end of the action.

[An Architectural View of the ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/AnArchitecturalViewOfTheASPNETMVCFramework.aspx) is a good start even it's a bit out of dated.

Answer (score 1):

There are many benefits (and also drawbacks) to MVC. First and foremost, it is a *design pattern* and not *replacing* other ASP.NET development (such as WinForms).

Read the following articles:

http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2008/11/25/howto-basics-of-aspnet-mvc-or-why-mvc/
http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/Advantages-of-the-ASPNET-MVC-Approach/
http://subjunctive.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/who-and-what-is-aspnet-mvc-for/

And also these questions on StackOverflow:

[Practical Application of MVC || When to use, or not use MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292557/practical-application-of-mvc-when-to-use-or-not-use-mvc)
[Is MVC the best way to code asp.net applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425306/is-mvc-the-best-way-to-code-asp-net-applications)